# Changing Abstract name does not work

Tags: environments, abstract, naming

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Serif} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\title{foo}
\author{me}
\date{}

 \addto\captionsgreek{%
    \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Εισαγωγή}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle  
\bigskip

\begin{abstract}
text.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

However, i cannot replace "abstract" with "Εισαγωγή".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an obvious issue in the example, that is, the main language is English and therefore `\captionsgreek` is never examined.

However, due to a weakness in how Greek is managed by `polyglossia`, you have to do

```
\appto\monogreekcaptions{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Εισαγωγή}}
```

Full example (with a different font, but it's irrelevant):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmainlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\appto\monogreekcaptions{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Εισαγωγή}}


\title{foo}
\author{me}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\bigskip

\begin{abstract}
text.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default translation is ‘Περιλήψη’. You can nest your abstract in a `greek` environment, and change the translation inside this environment – or not:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Serif}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\title{foo}
\author{me}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\bigskip
\begin{greek}
    \begin{abstract}
        Κείμενο.
    \end{abstract}
\end{greek}

\begin{greek}
    \def\abstractname{Εισαγωγή}
    \begin{abstract}
        Κείμενο.
    \end{abstract}
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

[image]